# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, macos-monterey

I am trying to setup tensorflow on mac os 12.3.1

I am using python 3.8.10 installed using pyenv

Commands i ran:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U setuptools
pip install tensorflow-macos
pip install tensorflow-metal
```

then in the `python` interpreter, i ran:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

and Error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Someone please help me solve this

thanks

Comment: did you try pip install _ctypes?

Comment: Does the command `brew list | grep -i libffi` output something in the terminal? If not, then you might have to install that package, and maybe reinstall Python again afterwards.

Comment: Yes, the command ```brew list | grep -i libffi``` gives an otput ```libffi```. Assuming that libffi is installed